# Is there any evidence that any philosophers in Antiquity viewed space itself as a something?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, metaphysics

In Lucretious poem *De Natura*, he has

> They [atoms] move through the void

In contemporary usage a *vacuum* is the the removal of all matter from *space*, it stems from Latin adjective [vacuus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum) for *empty* or *void*. What I am curious about is what was then (in Antiquity) understood by the *void*.

My understanding is that the greek atomists were forced to their theory by critiquing Parmenides monism where he denied the existence of the *void* (that is, *is not*) in his poem *Of Nature*:

> the one, that is and that *is not* not to be,
>
> ...
>
> but the other, that *is not* and that must not be,
>
> this, I tell you, is a path wholly without report:
>
> for neither could you apprehend what *is not*, for it is not to be accomplished,
>
> nor could you indicate it.

and

> but nothing it *is not*

It certainly seems that the Ash'arite atomists in Islamic Philosophy (the *Falsafa*) seemed to go that step further: understanding that space is something they atomised it too.

Certainly in contemporary physics there is no *void*. Space itself is *something*. Similarly in contemporary mathematics, for example: *zero* or *nothing* was first understood prosaically and negatively as the *lack* of something, and is now understood *positively* as a *process* (that is *functionally*), as the *identity* of the system within which these numbers inhabit. Another example: a manifold was first thought of inside euclidean space, this is the *extrinsic* view; now via a cut by Occams Razor a more parsimonius view, the more elegant view, is to remove the extrinsic euclidean space, this stage within which the manifold is placed and enacted and view it *intrinsically*, that is solely for-itself and in-itself.

Is there any evidence that any followers of Parmenides asserted this, that is Space is a something? Certainly it seems the obvious thing to assert if we take Parmenides seriously.

Comment: [The Atomists: Leukippos of Miletos (fl. 450 B.C.) and Demokritos of Abdera (fl. 420 B.C.)](http://kvmagruder.net/hsci/03-Egypt-Aegean/presocratics/09-atomists-420.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Space as an objective, *sui generis* reality was held by

1. the ancient atomists
2. Descartes (with his *res extensa*, "extended substance")
3. Newton (with his geometric substance, which he endowed with divine attributes)

For a discussion on the plenum and the vacuum according to the ancient atomists, and how they were ulta-realists about the reality of absolute space, see P. Duhem's [*Système du monde*, vol. 1, pp. 33](https://archive.org/stream/lesystmedumond01duhe#page/32/mode/2up)-5 or D. Nys's [*La notion d'espace*, ch. 1](https://archive.org/stream/lanotiondespac00nysd#page/18/mode/2up).

Answer (score 1):

There's quite an apt paragraph in [The Writings of Chuang Tzu](http://www.sacred-texts.com/tao/sbe40/sbe4006.htm#fr_176), dating from the 4th century BCE :-

> Starlight asked Non-entity, saying, 'Master, do you exist? or do you
>   not exist?'  He got no answer to his question, however, and looked
>   stedfastly to the appearance of the other, which was that of a deep
>   void.  All day long he looked to it, but could see nothing; he
>   listened for it, but could hear nothing; he clutched at it, but got
>   hold of nothing.*  Starlight then said, 'Perfect! Who can attain to
>   this?  I can (conceive the ideas of) existence and non-existence, but
>   I cannot (conceive the ideas of) non-existing non-existence, and still
>   there be a non-existing existence.  How is it possible to reach to
>   this?'

* A quotation from the Tao Te Ching, [chapter 14](http://www.sacred-texts.com/tao/sbe39/sbe39021.htm).

The OP asks for "any philosophers in Antiquity".  While obviously not greek, [The Tao Te Ching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tao_Te_Ching) (6th c. BCE) and [Chuang Tzu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chuang_tzu) (4th c. BCE) are quite contemporaneous with [Parmenides](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parmenides), (5th c. BCE).  Also, it does not seem unreasonable to suppose these ideas could travel.

The quoted text certainly seems to directly meditate upon the existence of space, rather than its non-existence.  Elsewhere in the Tao Te Ching the void is a rather key phenomenon -- almost "the womb of possibility".  However, it is difficult to gauge modern interpretation in the process of translation.  (A chinese version can be found [here](http://ctext.org/zhuangzi/knowledge-rambling-in-the-north#n2885).)

Comment: Great answer. Ancient Chinese philosophy counts as philosophy in antiquity - though the term does usualy seem to refer to Greek philosophy.